# Proof of $\sum_{n\ge0}^{ }n^{m}z^{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}{m+1\brace j+1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m-j}j!}{\left(1-z\right)^{j+1}}$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, generating-functions, stirling-numbers

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#cite_note-10) states that [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) satisfy the following relation:

> $$\sum_{n\ge0}^{ }n^{m}z^{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}{m+1\brace j+1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{m-j}j!}{\left(1-z\right)^{j+1}}$$

I know a similar relation which is as follows:

$$n^{m}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}{m\brace j}\binom{n}{j}j!\tag{$n,m\ge0$}$$

From here we have:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{r}n^{m}=\sum_{n=0}^{r}\sum_{j=0}^{m}{m\brace j}\binom{n}{j}j!$$

Using [Hockey-stick identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hockey-stick_identity) the expression transforms to:

$$\sum_{n=0}^{r}n^{m}=\sum_{j=0}^{m}{m\brace j}\binom{r+1}{j+1}j!$$

However the first one is new to me,can someone please give me a combinatorial and an algebraic way to proof of that?I wonder how using generating functions (possibly) and some combinations it can be proved.

Answer (score 1):

In seeking to prove that

$$\sum_{n\ge 0} n^m z^n =
\sum_{j=0}^m {m+1\brace j+1} \frac{(-1)^{m-j} j!}{(1-z)^{j+1}}$$

we require by extraction of the coefficient on $[z^n]$ that

$$n^m = \sum_{j=0}^m {m+1\brace j+1}
(-1)^{m-j} j! {n+j\choose j}$$

The RHS is by standard EGFs

$$(m+1)! [z^{m+1}] \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{j+1}}{(j+1)!}
(-1)^{m-j} j! {n+j\choose j}
\\ = m! [z^m] \exp(z) \sum_{j=0}^m \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^{j}}{j!}
(-1)^{m-j} j! {n+j\choose j}
\\ = m! [z^m] \exp(z) \sum_{j=0}^m (\exp(z)-1)^{j}
(-1)^{m-j} {n+j\choose j}.$$

Now because $(\exp(z)-1)^j = z^j+\cdots$ there is no contribution to
the coefficient extractor $[z^m]$ when $j\gt m$ and we may extend the
sum to infinity:

$$m! (-1)^m [z^m] \exp(z) \sum_{j\ge 0} (\exp(z)-1)^{j}
(-1)^j {n+j\choose j}
\\ = m! (-1)^m [z^m] \exp(z)
\frac{1}{(1+\exp(z)-1)^{n+1}}
\\ = m! (-1)^m [z^m] \exp(z) \exp(-(n+1)z)
\\ = m! (-1)^m [z^m] \exp(-nz)
= m! [z^m] \exp(nz) = n^m.$$

This is the claim.